# OAuth authorization without Twitter login page

Tags: php, twitter, oauth

I use http://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth PHP library for reaching the Twitter REST API. My config file has credentials:

```
<?php
$consumer_key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$consumer_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$login = 'xxx';
$passwd = 'xxx';
?>
```

Is it possible to get `oauth_token` and `oauth_token_secret` without showing the Twitter login page?

[image]

Comment: This shouldn't be possible; the whole point of oauth is that it requires that the end user be taken to Twitter to authorize the authentication and then return the token to the consumer (you).

Comment: That is the whole point of oAuth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the comments state, you can't do this. Once the you have authorised, you can then store the returns and use them in all your calls, keeping your connection "persistant"

Comment: Not sure why I got a downvote, but to backup my answer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521050/cron-automated-twitter-api-access

Answer (score 0):

go to http://dev.twitter.com/apps and click on your app

then, on the right side click on "My Access Tokens"